# Is it possible to read the content of a Microsoft Excel File before an Ajax Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, ajax

I am trying to validate a file before an upload. I am validating the filetype (i.e only allowing .xls, .xlsx), but I need to ensure they're submitting a specific Microsoft Excel file. This is crucial because I am uploading the data into a table. If the submits an Excel file, but it's the wrong one, the data in the table will be incorrect. The filename cannot be a way to validate it as I am not certain if the end-users will be keeping the same naming convention.

Is there anyway I can grab the name of the first colum?

Here's the code I have thus far.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    // label when file is selected
    $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        $('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
    });

    $("#btnUpload").click(function (event) {
    
    // validate filetype
    var fileID = document.getElementById('uploadEmpFile');
        fileName = fileID.value;
        fileType = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        console.log(fileType);

        if (fileType == "" || fileType == null) {
            alert('You never selected a file !');

        }
        else if (!(fileType == 'xlsx' || fileType == 'xls' || fileType == 'xlsm')) {
            alert('As it turns out, this particular file type is not compatible.');

        }
        else {
            //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get form
            var form = $('#fileUploadForm')[0];

            // Create an FormData object 
            var data = new FormData(form);

            // If you want to add an extra field for the FormData
            data.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data, testing");

            // disabled the submit button
            $("#btnUpload").prop("disabled", true);

            $('#loader').removeClass('d-none');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                url: "http://localhost:61591/api/Inservice/OfficeStaffUpload",
                data: data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                timeout: 100000,
                success: function (data) {
                    var responseData = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#loader").addClass("d-none");

                    if (responseData.result == "Success") {
                        alert('The Employee Roster has successfully been uploaded.');
                        window.location = "hrAdmin.html";
                        $("#btnUpload").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    $("#result").text(e.responseText);
                    console.log("ERROR : ", e);
                    $("#btnUpload").prop("disabled", false);

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You better to do that on the server, you can't trust any client-side validations.

Comment: yes. that should be done before insertion, but after the call. so on the server side it needs to validate.

Comment: Ok. I will look into that. Thank you !